# Changing string daily

Tags: android

I am making a daily Bible verse widget. I am working on making a string array with 236 different verses. I need the app to change the verse daily. I actually wanted to start on the string named 1 and go down the list in order. Is this possible or do I need to randomly call the strings?

Answer (score 1):

it will be based on your logic. Mine will be another column with a corresponding date for that row to show.. Then get the date on your device and ADD (like or equal) on my query (based on the column and the date registered on your device).

I dont know,.. its up to you as a Developer..

Cheers..

Comment: How would I go about making it where it would start on the day a user installed it?